# Help to pick the right bike between these two

Tags: road-bike

I need help to make the right choice between two bikes that are quite similar in terms of specifications. 
Could anyone reading this give me an advice ?

Bike A : Broodie Bike model "Ocho"
http://www.brodiebikes.com/2016/bikes/ocho.php

Bike B : TREK bike FX S 4
https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/hybrid-bikes/fitness-bikes/fx/fx-s-4/p/1341000-2017/

Please let me know your thoughts !

Thank you :)

Raphael

Comment: As always - the bike that gets used is the best bike.  So test them both and make sure you get the one on which you are most comfortable.  Generally this means visiting some bike shops in person.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'm partial to Trek as a brand. What I can say as to why I like the Trek more in this situation is because where the seat stays meet the seat tube are directly behind the top tube and give you more structural integrity. The Brodie's seat stays are higher than the top tube which might lead to the frame warping under weight sooner than the Trek. The Trek also comes pre-equipped with a carbon fork which is nice and offers some flex and shock absorption out of the box. It's Duotrap S ready, so all you need is the sensor, and that'll integrate into your frame allowing you to transmit statistics like speed and pedal cadence to your phone or compatible GPS unit if you're into the whole fitness/statistics thing. And it comes pre-equipped with a Shimano Tiagra groupset, which is 2x10 speeds; offering you more gearing than the Brodie does right out of the box.

The Brodie doesn't seem like a bad bike to me, but the Trek has way more going on for it as a fitness/commuter ride.

My personal gripe with both bikes is the lack of drop handlebars or STI shifters. Flat bars are nice for a quick run to the grocery store, but your arms and hands will be much more grateful after a long ride if you invest in drop handlebars and STI brake/shifters on either bike.

As far as my personal argument towards the Trek, it's made out of that good Alpha Aluminum, which is a proprietary alloy. I have a 17 year old X01 made out of the alpha aluminum, and it's still my favorite bike for commuting and recreational spins.

Comment: Its a good answer to an "off topic" question so +1 for the thought that went in.  These "shopping" questions are classed as off topic, mostly because of the limited use to other people in the future.  I look forward to your contributions on other questions too.